# Error sending more than 300 emails with PHP Swift Mailer showing Internal Server Error

Tags: php, swiftmailer, mailer

Error sending more than 300 emails with PHP Swift Mailer showing Internal Server Error getting only 200 mails out of 300

i am using ftp surfer

another problem is after sending 200 mails upto one hour mails are not going it showing us as send but i am not getting any mails after one hour again they are getting

mail ids are getting from mysql database

using for each loop mails are sending

```
        <?php    // Create the message

                                      // Create the message
                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();


                $sql=mysql_query("select * from test_email where status=''");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {



                // Usually you want to replace the following static array
                // with a dynamic one built retrieving users from the database
                $users = array(
                  array(
                    "fullname" => "Aurelio De Rosa",
                    "operations" => $row['sno'],
                    "email" => $row['email']
                  )
                );

                // Create the replacements array
                $replacements = array();
                foreach ($users as $user) {
                  $replacements[$user["email"]] = array (

                    "{fullname}" => $user["fullname"],
                    "{transactions}" => $user["operations"]
                  );
                }

                // Create the mail transport configuration
                $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

                // Create an instance of the plugin and register it
                $plugin = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
                $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
                $mailer->registerPlugin($plugin);

                // Create the message
                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
                $message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");

                // Create your file contents in the normal way, but don't write them to disk




                // Create your file contents in the normal way, but don't write 
            //them to disk

                $type = $message->getHeaders()->get('Content-Type');

                $type->setValue('text/html');
                $type->setParameter('charset', 'utf-8');


                // Use AntiFlood to re-connect after 100 emails
                $mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100));

                // And specify a time in seconds to pause for (30 secs)
                $mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 30));

                // Create the message
                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('My subject');

                // Set the body
                $message->setBody(
                '<html>' .
                ' <head></head>' .
                ' <body>' .
                '  Here is an image <img src="http://www.graymatter8.info/Developer1/swiftm/x.php?ts={transactions}&&ip='.$ip.'" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0"/>' .
                '  Rest of message' .
                ' </body>' .
                '</html>',
                  'text/html' // Mark the content-type as HTML
                );



                $message->setFrom("account@bank.com", "Testing");
                $failedRecipients = array();
                $numSent = 0;



                // Send the email
                foreach($users as $user) 
                {
                  $message->setTo($user["email"], $user["fullname"]);

                   $mailer->send($message);

                }
            ?>
```

Comment: You should be providing the error.

Comment: `Doctor, I am getting a symptom whenever I grasp a knife. I can only cut 2/3 of the tomato.` <- Please be more specific or else this is how your question is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You should send it out in packets, like 10-20 at once. As soon as a package is done, you can go to the next 10-20, and so on...

Comment: How can you tell this will eliminate the error without knowing it? Also, OP might already been doing that. You can't tell based on the current question.

Comment: I'm 95% sure because of the 500 error. I have experiences with mail sending. You'll surely run out of memory if you try to send 300 emails at once at a regular hosting service.

Comment: Well, you don't know all that you're claiming. There hosting environment is unknown. Restrictions are unknown. Even the code and error is unknown. So it may be a good guess, but if you have a hunch leave a comment instead. The question is unanswerable.

Comment: can u tell me how to take it from database through packets in for loop

Comment: You can't. I would suggest to create an HTML page with some jQuery Ajax. Paginate your queries, and call back to your PHP after every ajax call where you send out 20 emails for example. Than setTimeout for 5 seconds, than rerun ajax again. Until all users have been processed.

Comment: if you dont mind another question actulally after sending 200 mails upto 1 hour i cant send any mails after 1 hr only again they are going

Comment: Where do you host your site?

Comment: actually i dont know much details we just upload our files to ftp surfer so i have know idea about hosting details.If u tell me how to find hosting details i will check it out and post it here then u can clarify my doubt